# Int into foreach that doesn't increment

Tags: php, loops, foreach, int

I'm creating a formulary with a lot of things into it and i've a simple problem with my foreach.

Here is my code :

```
    foreach($aDonnes['Grilles'][$iGrilleId] as $iCptGrille){
       $sHtml .='<tr><td class="grille">'.($sGrilleLib=$aDonnes['Grilles'][$iCptGrille][1]).'</tr></td>';
       $aDonnes['Domaines']=$oRolling->find_domaines($iCptGrille);
    if ($iCptGrille < $aDonnes['Grilles'].length) {
        $iCptGrille++;
    }

    // Several nested foreach
```

I've tried without the if condition, or anything and it still doesn't increment when I check the logs, It just do the same thing again and again.

If you've any questions feel free to ask.

NB : $iCptGrille is my int that doesn't increment and aDonnes is an array that has a lot of data into it, and in our case this is for each ID of my Table called "Grille" that i want to loop.

Comment: It's a matter of scope : using the as keyword makes a copy of your actual array element.

Comment: Well.. thank's a lot ! Problem solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Answers_Seeker said, "It's a matter of scope : using the as keyword makes a copy of your actual array element".

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking a 2D array, I think the foreach input should be:

```
foreach($aDonnes['Grilles'] as $iCptGrille){...}
```

Also the counter name has the same name as the object item $iCptGrille, which doesn't make sense.

Also you can try initializing the counter by 0 before foreach block and remove 'if' statement if it's unnecessary.

For furthur investigations, you can use some kind of flag (for example `echo 'entered';` ) inside the foreach block, to make sure it enters into the foreach block.

I hope it helps.